# Create numpy array with class label and dataset

Tags: python, arrays

I wish to implement a code similar to the one below, given that i'm trying it on a new, similar dataset. What i need is to adjust it to what i have: 2 classes and 5 examples for each.
How to i put it in a numpy array in a similar fashion?

This is the original code:

```
train_split_path = os.path.join(root_dir, 'splits', 'train.txt')

with open(train_split_path, 'r') as train_split:
      train_classes = [line.rstrip() for line in train_split.readlines()]

#number of classes
no_of_classes = len(train_classes)

#number of examples
num_examples = 20

#image width
img_width = 28

#image height
img_height = 28
channels = 1

train_dataset = np.zeros([no_of_classes, num_examples, img_height, img_width], dtype=np.float32)


for label, name in enumerate(train_classes):
    alphabet, character, rotation = name.split('/')
    rotation = float(rotation[3:])
    img_dir = os.path.join(root_dir, 'data', alphabet, character)
    img_files = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(img_dir, '*.png')))


    for index, img_file in enumerate(img_files):
        values = 1. - np.array(Image.open(img_file).rotate(rotation).resize((img_width, img_height)), np.float32, copy=False)
        train_dataset[label, index] = values

train_dataset.shape
```

and the result is:

```
(4112, 20, 28, 28)
```

I don't have a txt file for the classes, given that their classes names go by 1 and 2.

This is the link for the original code:

https://github.com/sudharsan13296/Hands-On-Meta-Learning-With-Python/blob/master/03.%20Prototypical%20Networks%20and%20its%20Variants/3.3%20Omniglot%20Character%20set%20classification%20using%20Prototypical%20Network.ipynb

This is what i tried:

```
arr = []


def filter_banks(wav, arr):

a = filt_banks(r'...\vowels\2.wav', arr)

no_of_classes = len(a)

#number of examples
num_examples = 5

#image width
width = 28

#image height
height = 28
channels = 3

train_dataset = np.zeros([no_of_classes, num_examples, height, width], dtype=np.float32)

for i in range(len(a)):
    train_dataset[no_of_classes]=np.array(i).resize([height,width])
```

I get the following message:

```
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

How can i get a similar result to the previously stated?

Comment: i did'nt get what you are asking try to give minimum reproducible example, but what your error says is you are trying to acccess `index 2` which has to be of `size 3` because indexing in python starts with `0`, but axis 0 has only size of 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this except that replace np.zeros by an image matrix of size height and width

```
for label in number_of_classes:
    for example in number_of_examples:
        data[label,example] = np.zeros((height,width))
```